# Is there a function that automatically allocates ports?

Tags: web, server, port

Is there a way to automatically match users to different ports when accessing www.***.com?

Is it possible to change :80 to :10001 when connecting, and if someone is matched, change it to :10002?

Comment: Why? It's a highly unusual approach. Normally the entire server runs on one port per protocol. Are you just trying to rub multiple isolated  server sessions per user?

Comment: please define "users"

Comment: I'm currently trying to build a web hosted multigame.

Because it is a one-to-one hosting on the server, it is necessary to automatically allocate ports to individuals.

Comment: please define "individuals" and "users"

Comment: The user accesses www.***.com to play the game. At this time, the server tries to connect the user to the game in a 1-to-1 hosting method through Unreal Pixel Streaming.

ex) user1 connects to www.***.com and goes to port 81 for connection, user2 connects to www.***.com and goes to port 82. And through unreal gamelift login, user1 and user2 will meet on one multi-server.

If this is impossible to implement, I think I will have to find another way.

Comment: You would normally run a reverse proxy on port 80 to send different virtual hosts for different host names to different backend ports.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's likely not a way to do this automatically. Because it's rare to want to do something like this on a Web server.